# Scheme for showing integration by parts

Tags: equations

I am sorry for duplicate question, but I don't know to to call it to find it here. How can I please write this?

[image]

```
u = r_2^2
u' = 2r_2
v'=e^{-\frac{2Zr_2}{a}}
v = -\frac{a}{2Z} e^{-\frac{2Zr_2}{a}}
```

Comment: Search for `vmatrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this may help you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int x\mathbf{\ln} x\,dx=\begin{vmatrix}
\boldsymbol{u} = \ln x &\boldsymbol{u'}=\dfrac{1}{x}\\[12pt]
v'=x &v=\frac{x^2}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a cleaner syntax that also allows for different realizations of the scheme by only changing the definition and not the input.

In the second example, the lines would be too near to each other, so I added the `[1ex]` optional argument to space them up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\byparts}{O{0pt}m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { elisabeth/byparts } { #2 }
  \elisabeth_byparts:n { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { elisabeth/byparts }
 {
  u  .tl_set:N = \l__elisabeth_byparts_u_tl,
  u' .tl_set:N = \l__elisabeth_byparts_up_tl,
  v  .tl_set:N = \l__elisabeth_byparts_v_tl,
  v' .tl_set:N = \l__elisabeth_byparts_vp_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \elisabeth_byparts:n
 {
  \begin{vmatrix}\,\begin{aligned}
  & u  = \l__elisabeth_byparts_u_tl  && u' = \l__elisabeth_byparts_up_tl
  \\[#1]
  & v' = \l__elisabeth_byparts_vp_tl && v  = \l__elisabeth_byparts_v_tl
  \end{aligned}\,\end{vmatrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Without optional argument
\begin{equation*}
\int x\sin x\,dx =
\byparts{
  u  = x,
  u' = 1,
  v' = \sin x,
  v  = -\cos x
}
\end{equation*}
and with optional argument for opening up
\begin{equation*}
\int x\ln x\,dx =
\byparts[1ex]{
  u  = \ln x,
  u' = \frac{1}{x},
  v' = x,
  v  = \frac{x^2}{2}
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For instance, after seeing the result I opted for not aligning at equals signs, but it would be possible by changing the definition of `\elisabeth_bypart:n`. If I change it into

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \elisabeth_byparts:n
 {
  \begin{vmatrix}\,\begin{aligned}
  u\hphantom{'} &= \l__elisabeth_byparts_u_tl
  &
  u' &= \l__elisabeth_byparts_up_tl
  \\[#1]
  v' &= \l__elisabeth_byparts_vp_tl
  &
  v\hphantom{'} &= \l__elisabeth_byparts_v_tl
  \end{aligned}\,\end{vmatrix}
 }
```

the output would become, *with no change to the document code*,

[image]